# Best way (with jQuery) to check that an empty <option> is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I'm using ASP.Net's drop-down helpers, and they produce HTML like this:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
    <option>Please Choose</option>
    <option value="1">Name A</option>
    <option value="2">Name B</option>
    <option value="3">Name B</option>
</select>
```

I want to validate that this `<select>` is not set to the *Please Choose* `<option>` in lots of places. Often the text is something other than *Please Choose*, but the `<option value>` attribute is always skipped for the default option.

The problem is that if you request the `value` and it is not set you get the `option`'s text:

```
// Gets value as 'Please Choose'
var value = $('#mySelect').val();

// Also gets the value as 'Please Choose'
var value = $('#mySelect option:selected').attr('value');
```

I want a check that returns true only if the `<option value>` attribute is actually populated.

My best solution to this so far is:

```
// Check that the value and text of an option are different
var value = $('#mySelect').val();
var selectedOptionText = $('#mySelect option:selected').text();
var check = value  != selectedOptionText;
```

This doesn't seem very reliable though - if we get an option like `<option value="1">1</option>` it will never appear to be valid.

Is there any way to check that the `<option value>` attribute is empty?

I'm using jQuery here but a pure Javascript solution would be good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
    if(!$("#mySelect option:selected").is('[value]'))
        console.log('no value');
});
```

Working http://jsfiddle.net/5ht7g/

Comment: I think `if($('#mySelect option[value]:selected').text()=='')` is more simple no?

Comment: Its the same thing... But techincally speaking, my if condition is 45 characters and yours is 47.

Comment: but your solution `return` only a `boolean`, with the second solution he can check and get the `value`. But he's only ask for the best way to check :D

Answer (score 2):

Use the `option[value]` to select only `options` with attribute `value`:

```
var selectedOptionText = $('#mySelect option[value]:selected').text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/tqVUp/

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the option has an attribute value :

```
if($('#mySelect option:selected').attr('value')) { ... }
```

Note :

Strangely, for this case, with some jQuery versions (it works with v1.9.1), `.attr('value') !== [0].value` -> the DOM value refers to the text when there is no value, but the `attr` function returns `undefined`.

Example : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/bq7Qb/1)

---

**EDIT :**

it looks like `$('#mySelect option:selected')[0].getAttribute("value")` gives null in almost cases (tested on FF / Chrome / IE8&9). On IE7, it gives an empty string...

Comment: That doesn't work.  The value will still be the text of the selected option.

Comment: @TimWithers yes, that's a bit strange, but I have tested and you're right... But strangely enough `.attr(value)` works correctly...

Comment: I was getting at this in the question `$('#mySelect option:selected').attr('value')` returns the text. What I really wanted was a check for the value attribute at all.

Comment: @Keith : ok, I guess is it your jQuery version that don't give you the same result, but if you check the jsFiddle, using jQuery 1.9.1, I obtain `undefined` when there is no value attached!

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie ah! Yes, it's how you describe in 1.9.1, but like I describe in 1.8.3 and below. We're on 1.7.2 (at least until we update all the pages still using `live`)

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a blank value to the default option? Like so:

```
<option value="">Please Choose</option>
```

Then you can use this jquery:

```
if($("select").val() === ''){
    alert('no item chosen');
}
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yKJh7/)

Comment: In this case I'm using an build in helper in .Net that renders the default `<option>` without a value. I don't really want to roll my own and I have a whole team using them that would need to switch.